# Movie about a bridge accident, people dying horribly and premonition

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, comedy

I saw a short fragment of a movie I would like to identify. **Warning: graphic descriptions follow**.

The film is contemporary, as far as I remember the cars were from the 90'. Set in the US.

The fragment was about group of friends who were in a bus when the bridge they were crossing started to break into pieces (it is a big hanging bridge, à la Golden Bridge). The group (of about 5) was fairly young (teens / young adults), American, white.

One of the boys was trying to help his friends to get back to a safe part of the bridge but they were dying one after the other, in a horrible yet somehow "humoristic" way:

- a girl lost her glasses, could not see much and was crossing a gap in the bridge over a narrow steel beam. She fell into the water but survived. Then a car fell from the bridge and killed her (you could see the car falling POV style)
- another girl (or boy, I do not remember) fell from the bridge, right on the mast of a boat which pierced her. The intestines are all over the place.
- someone gets a beam falling right though his head, the eye pops out.

One of the girls successfully crosses the steel beam.

Then suddenly a boy wakes up (we see his face and his eyes snapping open), it was a dream. He is in the bus with his friends and realizes he is about to cross the bridge and that the dream was a premonition. There is a problem ahead, the bus stops and he forces his friends to leave the bus to escape, they do not take him seriously but eventually leave with him. An older man tries to calm everyone down and stays behind. The bridge starts to have problems (cracks, some cables snap)

This is the fragment I saw, a total of maybe 3 or 4 minutes.

It looks like it is in the horror / black comedy style. I did not recognize any actors but I would not have anyway.

Comment: From the title I thought for sure this would be "Mothman Prophesies," but the description makes it not so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [**Final Destination 5**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1622979/) (2011)

> Sam Lawton is on his way to a company retreat with his colleagues. While their bus crosses the North Bay Bridge, Sam has a premonition that the bridge will collapse, killing everyone on it, except for his ex-girlfriend Molly Harper, who he manages to get across the bridge safely. In a panic, he persuades several people to leave the bridge before it collapses.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Destination_5)</sup>

Comment: I was just about to add my answer saying Final Destination 2, which also involves a major high way accident (though not on a bridge). It's funny to see that the plot of these movies hasn't really changed from movie to movie.

Comment: @onewho  no FD2 scene was way different and had no bridge.

Comment: @onewho - I think that's more-or-less the point.  But they're pretty fun nonetheles.

Comment: @onewho I usually never guess the movie, but for the description I guess was some Final Destination. The thing is I never watch one of those, only some trailers, so you are right they are the same.

Comment: There were seriously ***five*** of these things?

Comment: @Sidney well the *first* one was a decent, rather refreshing slasher movie ("the killer" was *death itself*, rather than some psycho with a knife)... the other four were just more of the same. So yeah... they should definitely have left it at one.